# How to check for a particular data of one data frame in some other data frame using R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I have two data frames called df1 and df2, and df1 has 2 columns named `poi`, `score`. And the another data frame df2 has only one column called `poi_` and it contains a few common data from df1$poi. I would be needing to check which df2$poi_ have their score defined in df1$poi and if score is present then put a new column called `score_` in df2 and fill the column with the score found in df1

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your `df1` and `df2`.

Comment: `df2$score_ <- df1[df2$poi_,"score"]`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
res <- merge(df2,df1,by.x="poi_",by.y="poi")
names(res)[2] <- "score_"
```